# How to pass a variable in phtml/php file to js file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

**This is about the Magento e-commerce website.**
I now need to pass a variable from view.phtml to product.js.

Firstly, i created a if statement in the php file(view.phtml) in order to get the discount rate form the database:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    //echo $customerData->getemail();

    $conn = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

            $sql = 'select max(sl.discount_amount) from salesrule sl 
                    join salesrule_customer_group scg on scg.rule_id = sl.rule_id
                    join customer_entity ce on ce.group_id = scg.customer_group_id
                    where ce.email = "'.$customerData->getemail().'";';

        $results = $conn->fetchAll($sql);
        //echo $results;
    }



    else
        { $factor =  100;} //only apply to NOTLOGGED IN's custom option price label



    foreach ($results as $result){
        {   $factor = $result['max(sl.discount_amount)'];
        }
        //echo '<small> Discounted price: </small> $',$prices*($factor/100);        
    }
```

As you see the method is retuning the $factor as result, and i need to pass this variable  $factor in the product.js(javascript) file.

```
  var subPrice = 0;
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;


            //var a = test;
            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax); // this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    //so need to change somewhere else in the same time to full fill the requirementirement
                    // but it doesn;t change to backend value
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);
                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                }
            });
            excl += subPrice;//also affect the final price *frontEnd
            incl += subPriceincludeTax;
```

I tried to pass it by JSON but it doesn't work at all and i cannot figure out the reason. I have something like `echo json_encode($factor);` to verify the output and it looks fine but still not able to pass in to the external js file.

Can anyone help? Thank you

**UPDATE 1:**
In the php file i added these :

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>); 

var tester = "<?php echo json_encode($factor);?>"
</script>
```

And pass these codes to the js like:

```
var subPrice = 0;
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var tester = tester;

            //var a = test;
            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax)*tester; // this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    //so need to change somewhere else in the same time to full fill the requirementirement
                    // but it doesn;t change to backend value
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);
                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                }
            });
            excl += subPrice;//also affect the final price *frontEnd
            incl += subPriceincludeTax;
```

But this doesn't seem to be working :(

**UPDATE 2**
According to outlooker i tried to added the input type in the phtml file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>); //the var of the option price, disable to disable price options

**<input type="hidden" id="factorDiscount" value="<?php echo $factor;?>"/>**
</script>
```

Afterward I also implement the var into the js file, call and use it as well:

```
    var subPrice = 0;
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var factor = $("#factorDiscount").val();//is not global


            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax)*factor; // this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);
                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                }
            });
```

It doesn't work now but i understand what you mean, but i might not inserting the codes in the right way. Any comment? Sir. Thank you

**UPDATE 3**
Thanks you for your help, sir. I inserted the code in the phtml file perfectly, but when i try to use it, it doesn't seem it's getting the data from the php

```
var subPrice = 0;
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var factor = $("#factorDiscount").val();//I declare the var here


            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax)*factor; // trying to times the var factor with the price but don't know if i am doing the right things.
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);
                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                }
            });
```

Comment: save the value in a hidden field and access it via javascript

Comment: mind to give me some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add an input hidden field and assign the `$factor` variable to it after the $`factor` variable has been initialized.Then access this variable via javascript

Say
In your phtml file add

```
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        //echo $customerData->getemail();

        $conn = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

                $sql = 'select max(sl.discount_amount) from salesrule sl 
                        join salesrule_customer_group scg on scg.rule_id = sl.rule_id
                        join customer_entity ce on ce.group_id = scg.customer_group_id
                        where ce.email = "'.$customerData->getemail().'";';

            $results = $conn->fetchAll($sql);
            //echo $results;
        }



        else
            { $factor =  100;} //only apply to NOTLOGGED IN's custom option price label



        foreach ($results as $result){
            {   $factor = $result['max(sl.discount_amount)'];
            }
            //echo '<small> Discounted price: </small> $',$prices*($factor/100);        
        } 

?>
    <input type="hidden" id="factorDiscount" value="<?php echo $factor;?>"/> 
//Hidden field added here

<?php
  //If you have other codes place it here
?>
```

In the js file access the above variable using

```
var factor = $("#factorDiscount").val();
```

I hope this is what you meant mate . :)

Comment: Thank you, but please do check my latest update, i am pretty new to these kind of modification.

Comment: Add the hidden field after the `foreach ($results as $result){
        {   $factor = $result['max(sl.discount_amount)'];
        }`

Comment: Not inside the script tag

Comment: `foreach ($results as $result)
   { $factor = $result['max(sl.discount_amount)'];}
   '<input type="hidden" id="factorDiscount" value="<?php echo $factor;?>"/>;` i insert it right after the line but with '' because the php not allowing html tag? Sorry i am a rookie

Comment: it makes my page empty when i insert the hidden input type tag like u mention in your answer

Answer (score 0):

If your external js file has the `.js` extension, it will probably not get processed as php and the php source code will remain there, breaking the javascript.

There are several ways to get around this, for example:

- Change the extension of your js file to `.php`;
- Pass the variable via the page script / magento and check if it exists in your external js file.
- Set up the server to process all `.js` files as php files;

Comment: I presume the only way i can pick is "Pass the variable via the page script / magento and check if it exists in your external js file."  see the update code please

Comment: @anson920520 That is what I normally use as php in my js means I cannot minimize, cache, etc..

Comment: I am too , but  i am using a e-commerice call Magento and it's structure is like this

Comment: You should check the source of the html / javascript, what does it look like? And check the scope of the generated javascript variables.

Comment: I am looking at the source in the same time but it's just too big, takes me forever to dig things out. Anyway thanks